# Get number of rows of query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want that my query show the total of results that obtain.

For example, if i execute this query:

```
SELECT user, email FROM users WHERE user = 'Daniel';
```

Show a third column with the total rows. With `user = 'Daniel'` i have a total of 13 records and that's how I want to show it:

```
user          email                total
-------------------------------------------------
Daniel        email1@gmail.com     13
Daniel        email2@gmail.com     13
Daniel        email3@gmail.com     13
Daniel        email4@gmail.com     13
....
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Whats wrong with using `COUNT`?

Comment: Where should this number come from? Can you share sample input data?

Comment: Why do you want same count repeating for all rows in a group?

Comment: I have no link to it.. . But i think this is a duplicate. This is definitely done by someone. Remember that Google is your best friend to find such a information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
 SELECT u2.user, u2.email,
(select count(*) from users u1 where u1.user=u2.user ) as total
  FROM users u2
 WHERE u2.user = 'Daniel';
```

in case mysql version >=8.0 then you can use count() window function

```
select user,email,count(*) over()  as total
from  users
     WHERE user = 'Daniel'
```

Comment: Your first query is not optimal, and a join would perform better.

Comment: Also what if there are duplicates in count

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja have you get any instruction about duplication in question ?? btw down vote is great but first know does really need to put doen vote then pl do it

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using analytic functions here:

```
SELECT
    user,
    email,
    COUNT(*) OVER () total
FROM users
WHERE user = 'Daniel';
```

If you can't use analytic functions, because you are using an earlier version of MySQL, then use a join:

```
SELECT
    u1.user,
    u1.email,
    u2.cnt AS total
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT user, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM users
    -- we could also restrict to Daniel here, but I am showing a general
    -- solution for multiple users
    GROUP BY user
) u2
    ON u1.user = u2.user
WHERE
    u1.user = 'Daniel';
```

Comment: What is the benefit to using this method as opposed to the others?

Comment: @Mark The analytic function version only requires (in theory) passing over the original table once.  The correlated subquery and join versions require additional subqueries.

Comment: @Tim does over() means all columns by default in analytic functions?

Comment: `OVER()` specifies no partition at all, which then defaults to meaning over the entire table.  Try it out yourself to see how it works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen does `OVER()` works on MariaDB also?

Comment: Yeah i get it as you din specify any partitioning column in Over so its over whole.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand why do you require the same count repeating for all rows in a group. Nevertheless the below query does the same thing you want

```
    Select user, email, count(distinct *) 
       over
     () as total from table ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the negative vote ive edited though i forgot the fact that OP wanted whole count not that just one partition

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports `COUNT(DISTINCT)` when used as an analytic function.

Comment: Perhaps i guess thats standard and should work with analytical too